# Why is the scope of a javascript function passed as a parameter 'window' -- and how do I make the scope its parent class?

Tags: javascript, parameters, scope, callback

Consider the following code:

```js
var myClass = {
  bar: function(){
     document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = this; // this is 'window' -- but I would like it to be 'myClass'
  },
  foo: function(callback){

    callback();
  }

}

myClass.foo(myClass.bar);
```

```html
The scope is: <span id='display'></span>
```

Why is the scope of bar 'window' instead of 'myClass' when it is called from a callback parameter -- and how do I make the scope 'myClass'?

Comment: That's context, not scope.

Answer (score 2):

When you are passing the function object, `myClass.bar` to `myClass.foo`, only the function object `bar` is passed. It doesn't know about which object it was from. So, there is no relation between `myClass` and `bar` in `foo` function.

> Why is the scope of bar 'window' instead of 'myClass' when it is called from a callback parameter

Since `callback` is not attached to any object, JavaScript will by default, use the global object (`window` object) as the `this` value.

> how do I make the scope 'myClass'

Its actually called context, not scope. To fix it, you can explicitly bind `myClass`, with [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fbind), like this

```
myClass.foo(myClass.bar.bind(myClass));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do this:

```
var myClass = {
  bar: function(){
     console.log(this.str); 
  },
  foo: function(callback){
    callback.apply(this); // --> set this as the scope
  },
  str:3
}

myClass.foo(myClass.bar); // outputs 3
```